# Asp.Net Identity 2.0 on ResetPassword Unable to connect to SQL Server database.Error on Azure web app

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-identity-2

I received this error when I try to reset password after I publish to Azure server. However, it works on localhost and all other functions are working on live like Register, ConfirmEmail and Login .. etc.
Error :

```
Unable to connect to SQL Server database. Method Message:, LogException: System.Web.HttpException: Unable to connect to SQL Server database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

My connection string in azure looks like :

```
Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MyDb;User ID=username;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True
```

with option `Custom`

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue on my side, ``ChangePassword`` functionality works in my web app both on local and Azure. You can try to [remote debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) your web app to check the connection of the ``dbcontext`` in controller action ``ChangePassword(ChangePasswordViewModel model)``. Besides, if possible, you can share your project and then I can test your code to find the issue.

Comment: Verify your Azure *server name* and the *firewall rules*

Answer (score 0):

> I received this error when I try to reset password after I publish to Azure server. However, it works on localhost and all other functions are working on live like Register, ConfirmEmail and Login .. etc. Error :
>
> ```
> Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
> ```

All functionalities/operations `Register`, `Login` and `RestPassword` should connect to same SQL Server database,  only resting password operation return the error, which is strange. I cannot reproduce the issue on my side, Please specify connection string name using Azure SQL database for your application on local  and do `RestPassword` operation in your local application, and check if it still works fine on local.

And please check if the database connection string of ***DbContext*** is the one that you want to use and if the database is accessible.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Besides, as I mentioned in comment,  you can try to [remote debug your web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) to check the actual connection of the DbContext  in controller action and make sure if these `Register`, `Login` and `RestPassword` operations are connecting to same SQL Server database.